# Excel 2016 32 Bit Macro throwing Macro Error on Excel 2016 64 Bit - Tried PtrSafe (Both Codes below)

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit, 32-bit

After trying community solutions, it is still throwing errors on 64 bit or I break it enough to make it non functional completely.

This impacts work tremendously and am trying to get it working quickly so really appreciate all of you and your help with this.

P.S. I only have Excel 32 Bit so have to bother another team member to validate as well, which delays it even further.

The Actual Code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Sub RemoveCaption(objForm As Object)
    Dim lStyle          As Long
    Dim hMenu           As Long
    Dim mhWndForm       As Long
    If Val(Application.Version) < 9 Then
        mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", objForm.Caption) 'XL97
    Else
        mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", objForm.Caption) 'XL2000+
    End If
    lStyle = GetWindowLong(mhWndForm, -16)
    lStyle = lStyle And Not &HC00000
    SetWindowLong mhWndForm, -16, lStyle
    DrawMenuBar mhWndForm
End Sub
```

My attempt with PtrSafe:

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _
Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#End If
Sub RemoveCaption(objForm As Object)
    Dim lStyle          As Long
    Dim hMenu           As Long
    Dim mhWndForm       As Long
    If Val(Application.Version) < 9 Then
        mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", objForm.Caption) 'XL97
    Else
        mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", objForm.Caption) 'XL2000+
    End If
    lStyle = GetWindowLong(mhWndForm, -16)
    lStyle = lStyle And Not &HC00000
    SetWindowLong mhWndForm, -16, lStyle
    DrawMenuBar mhWndForm
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not done with adding `PtrSafe` to make it compatible with 64bit. **Some** but not all `Long` need to convert to `LongPtr` too. Check againts https://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt to find the correct syntax for 64bit.  • Make sure you use the correct types in your procedures/subs too. If the function waits for a `Long` you **must** submit a `Long` if it waits for a `LongPtr` you must submit a `LongPtr` if you don't get it right there is a high probability your Excel crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe part of your issue will be coming from GetWindowLongA.  From the documentation on that function:

> Note  If you are retrieving a pointer or a handle, this function has been superseded by the GetWindowLongPtr function. (Pointers and handles are 32 bits on 32-bit Windows and 64 bits on 64-bit Windows.) To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use GetWindowLongPtr.

As I understand it that will be causing issues.  It is also worth noting that the returned values from the function is variable based off the OS.  IE 64 bit OS returns QWORD Pointer and 32 but OS a DWORD.

Comment: Ed,

Thanks for the prompt response to my question/issue. I am testing out the changes to GetWindowLongPtr.

The modified my version code is not throwing any errors on the Excel 64 Bit, except almost all my drop downs on the sheet are non functional. Maybe your solution about takes care of it.

Fortunately, all systems are running Win 10 or Win 7 64 Bit OS. It is the Microsoft product which is different. The Excel sheet in question is distributed to over 300 people and only one person is using Excel 64 bit. 

Thanks again. Will try the change you suggested and update.

Comment: Ed, after implementing, it does rid the error however, the drop downs are still non-functional on the 64bit. Other changes throw Compile errors as well as crash the 32 bit working version as well.